# What is the serverless.yml file on serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a short question. The serverless.yml of the serverless framework is a wrapper of aws cloudformation yml or how does it work?

Comment: Yeah, the serverless framework is mostly a layer on top of Cloudformation. It has more specific goals than cloudformation, which makes the config more simple. AWS SAM is the same concept.

Comment: added a answer hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SAM and serverless frameworks have in common that they generate CloudFormation.
- they both abstract CloudFormation so that you need to write less code to build serverless applications (in the case of SAM) and to deploy Lambda functions (for both SAM and Serverless).

**Yes they are abstraction, however serverless allows you to granularize more.**